# angular want to set value and valid it( ng-valid, ng-dirty, ng-touched)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am very new to Angular, my form has an input field, I have to key press to validate it.

I don't want to press any key. I wanted to do set the value to the input field and validate ( update status ) the field.

```
<body>
<app-root _nghost-c0="" ng-version="6.1.10">
<app-home _nghost-c1="" class="ng-star-inserted"><form _ngcontent-c11="" novalidate="" class="ng-invalid ng-untouched ng-pristine"><p-autocomplete _ngcontent-c11="" aria-label="Enter To station. Input is Mandatory." delay="100" id="destination" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-untouched">
<input autocomplete="off" class="ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-autocomplete-input ng-star-inserted" type="text" placeholder="To*" ng-model="to">
<div class="ui-autocomplete-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="display: none; width: 100%; max-height: 200px;"></div>
</p-autocomplete>
<button _ngcontent-c11="" class="search_btn" label="Find Results" type="submit">Find Results</button>
</form>
</app-home>
</app-root>
</body>
```

Comment: can u create a demo on https://stackblitz.com/ and share us the url. Update the comment section so that I'll be informed

Comment: can't tell if its template or reactive. looks like a run-time html rather than development template code.